# Three-manifolds related by degree 1 map, whose products with the two-sphere are diffeomorphic

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are compact oriented smooth 3-manifolds such that there is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism between the products $F:M \times S^2 \to N \times S^2$. Further, there are points $m \in M$ and $n \in N$ such that $F$ takes $\{m\} \times S^2$ to $\{n\} \times S^2$. Are $M$ and $N$ diffeomorphic?

I remark that one can choose a section of the trivial bundle $\sigma:M \to M \times S^2$, and then, $f:=\pi_N \circ F \circ \sigma :M \to N$ is a degree one map. This is because $f^{-1}(f(m))=\{m\}$ and $df:T_m M \to T_n N$ is an orientation-preserving isomorphism.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133135/3-manifolds-with-diffeomorphic-unit-tangent-bundles

Comment: @PVAL Thanks for pointing it out. The hypothesis in that problem are weaker though. Here we additionally have that the diffeomorphism takes $\{m\} \times S^2$ to $\{n\} \times S^2$.

Comment: Presumably you noticed that it's true if one of your manifolds is irreducible and not a lens space, since in that case the diffeomorphism type is determined by the fundamental group.